# Visual Force Page tag

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Written Apex Class:

```
public class one{
   public PageReference method() {
      return null;
   }
   public string acName{set;get;}
   public integer acPhone{set;get;}
   public List<Account> accs{set;get;}
   public string accid {set;get;}
   public pagereference save(){
       //accid = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       accs = [select id,name,phone,type from account limit 10];
       return null;
   }
}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                <apex:column >
                <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="two">
                <apex:param name="accountName" value="{!a.name}" assignTo="{!acName}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock id="two">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                ID:{!acName}
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

what is the use of this Line:

`<apex:param name="accountName" value="{!a.name}" assignTo="{!acName}"/>`

if I Remove this Line also it is Not showing any Effect in the output,anyone explains the Logic for `<apex:param>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general term, the `<apex:param>` tag is used to pass values from JavaScript to an Apex controller, it can be used with the following parent tags.

> apex:actionFunction
>
> apex:actionSupport
>
> apex:commandLink
>
> apex:outputLink
>
> apex:outputText
>
> flow:interview

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="two">
    <apex:param name="accountName" value="{!a.name}" assignTo="{!acName}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

In general word, when you click on this button. `apex:param` will assign the `a.name` value to controller `acName` variable. This way you can get the Account name in controller

Comment: when i click the command button No action is Performed in the output, how to identify for the apex param value, shall i set any Debug log for this apex class

Comment: what value should store in {!a name}, what Value should assigned,Please anyone explain Clearly

Comment: @user36188 whatever value will have in account.name that value will assign to acName variable..

Comment: what is the use of <apex param>

Comment: @ Ratan only assigning Purposes, I want to display the acname Values in Vf Page

Comment: Then only I will Understand the logic

Comment: @user36188 you should able to see the account name after clicking the button. because after assigning the name you are rerendering, it should display the name

Comment: after clicking only the <apex:param> tag is used ah?

Comment: @user36188 got the Account name after rerender ?

Comment: @user36188 ok great

Comment: why they are devoting My Question , I want to see the people who are Devoting how @Ratan

Comment: @user36188 not sure .. this is kind of strange, you are just asking about the param... I upvoted your answer :-)

Comment: You are always Great @Ratan